# Hardy type inequality with singular weights

Tags: inequalities, functional-equations

Recall that Hardy's inequality involving distance from the boundary of a convex set $\Omega \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n ; n \geq 1$, asserts that
$$
\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^p \, d x \geq\left(\frac{p-1}{p}\right)^p \int_{\Omega} \frac{|u|^p}{d^p} \, d x, \quad p>1,
$$
for all $u \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, where $d \equiv d(x):=\operatorname{dist}\left(x, \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \Omega\right)$ is the distance function.

Now, let $\Omega $  be a smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and  $a\in \Omega$. Can we have the following  Hardy type inequality:  $$
    \int_{\Omega} \frac{|w|^2}{|x-a|^2|\ln | x-a||^2} \leq c\|w\|^2, \quad\forall\, w\in H_0^1(\Omega), $$where $c$ is a constant but independent on $w$.

Comment: what would be the intuition behind it? Did you try the inequalities from "Hardy Inequalities for Nonconvex Domains" https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4419-1341-8_1

Comment: Sorry, this equality is actually from some paper I recently read.

Comment: The paper is ``On a resonant mean field type equation: a critical point at infinity approach", the inequality appears in the end of the proof of Lemma A.5. I'm not sure how to obtain such inequality. or I can send the paper to your email if possible.

Comment: see the link: www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/dcds.2017075